# VBScript iterating through XML child nodes and retrieving values

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have the following XML provided by a customer from which I need to extract items like:

- `<CustomerProductName>`
- `<ProductName>`
- `<ProductAssetName>`

Treating each `<CustomerProducts>` section as a seperate order.

I can get to `<CustomerProducts>` and extract the `<CustomerProductName>` without a problem and iterate over the value in each section.

But I can't see how I get to the values below it.  If someone could someone give me some pointers as to how to achieve thIs would be gratefull as I have been trying for over a day now.

The basic code is below the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products_Root>
    <Products_IPN VendorID="11344" >
        <CustomerProducts CustomerProductName="Test" ProductCount="7">
            <Products ProductType="BOOK" ProductName="Donald" >
                <ProductComponents ProductAssetName="Donald.pdf" />
                <ProductSpecs SpecClass="MEASUREMENT" SpecType="MARGINS" SpecValue="PER FILE"/>
                <ProductSpecs SpecClass="OPERATION" SpecType="BIND" SpecValue="SADDLE"/>
            </Products>
            <Products ProductType="BOOK" ProductName="Duck">
                <ProductComponents ProductAssetName="Duck.pdf"/>
                <ProductSpecs SpecClass="MEASUREMENT" SpecType="MARGINS" SpecValue="PER FILE"/>
                </Products>
        </CustomerProducts>
        <CustomerProducts CustomerProductName="Test2" ProductCount="2">
            <Products ProductType="BOOK" ProductName="Micky">
                <ProductComponents ProductAssetName="Mouse.pdf" />
                <ProductComponents ProductAssetName="Mouse.pdf" />
                <ProductSpecs SpecClass="MEASUREMENT" SpecType="MARGINS" SpecValue="PER FILE"/>
            </Products>
            <CustomerProductSpecs SpecClass="OPERATION" SpecType="KITTING" SpecValue="SHRINKWRAP KIT"/>
        </CustomerProducts>
        <CustomerProducts CustomerProductName="Test3" ProductCount="6">
            <Products ProductType="BOOK" ProductName="Minnie">
                <ProductComponents ProductAssetName="Mouse" />
                <ProductSpecs SpecClass="MEASUREMENT" SpecType="MARGINS" SpecValue="PER FILE"/>
            </Products>
        </CustomerProducts>
    </Products_IPN>
</Products_Root>
```

And here my VBScript code so far

```
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("E:\dropbox\Dropbox\Hobbs\Xerox Example Files\test.xml")

Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CustomerProducts")

plot="No Value"
If objNodeList.length > 0 then
    For each x in objNodeList
        JobName=x.getattribute("CustomerProductName")
        msgbox JobName
    Next
Else
    msgbox chr(34) & "CustomerProducts" & chr(34) & " field not found."
End If
```

Answer (score 7):

You already set the selection language to XPath, maybe you should *use* it, too. :)

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim xmlDoc, CustomerProducts, Products
Dim plot, CustomerProductName, ProductName

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load "products.xml"

plot = "No Value"

For Each CustomerProducts In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//CustomerProducts")
  CustomerProductName = CustomerProducts.getAttribute("CustomerProductName")

  For Each Products In CustomerProducts.SelectNodes("./Products")
    ProductName = Products.getAttribute("ProductName")

    MsgBox CustomerProductName & " - " & ProductName
  Next
Next
```

Comment: <return> sends the post, must remember that ;)<br />  To het to the lower structures <ProductComponents><ProductSpecs> etc, do I use a `For Each` process or can I refference them in another way i.e. <br /> `ASSET = "./Products/ProductSpecs"`<br />

Comment: My answer shows the way to use XPath (`SelectNodes()`). If you don't want to loop over the nodes, then you don't need to use `For Each`. It will be helpful to have a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761386(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out what other methods and properties are available.

Comment: Tomalak,

thanks for the advice yesterday, it helped greatly :)

I have updated code but it's too big for the text box, how would I best share it?

Comment: @Greybeard There is no upper limit for the code you publish here. Nevertheless it's advisable to keep the code samples small. Nobody likes digging through tons of foreign code.