# How do I iterate xml files that have many of the same tag per record?

Tags: xml-parsing, asp-classic

I'm working on an old classic asp system that receives an xml file from another system that has recently changed the format of the xml file.  It contains a video library summary I need to parse.

Sample xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<videodb>
    <version>1</version>
    <movie>
        <title>3 Days to Kill</title>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>6.000000</value>
                <votes>1416</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
        <plot>A dangerous international spy... blah blah blah</plot>
        <runtime>113</runtime>
        <mpaa>Rated PG-13</mpaa>
        <id>tt2172934</id>
        <uniqueid type="imdb" default="true">tt2172934</uniqueid>
        <uniqueid type="tmdb">192102</uniqueid>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <year>2014</year>
        <status></status>
        <code></code>
        <trailer></trailer>
        <actor>
            <name>Kevin Costner</name>
            <role>Ethan Renner</role>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Amber Heard</name>
            <role>Vivi Delay</role>
        </actor>
        <dateadded>2014-12-21 14:31:07</dateadded>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>47 Ronin</title>
        <ratings>
            <rating name="themoviedb" max="10" default="true">
                <value>6.000000</value>
                <votes>2324</votes>
            </rating>
        </ratings>
        <plot>Kai—an outcast—joins Oishi, the leader of 47 outcast samurai...blah blah blah</plot>
        <runtime>119</runtime>
        <mpaa>Rated PG-13</mpaa>
        <playcount>1</playcount>
        <lastplayed>2020-03-24</lastplayed>
        <id>tt1335975</id>
        <uniqueid type="imdb" default="true">tt1335975</uniqueid>
        <uniqueid type="tmdb">64686</uniqueid>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <genre>Action</genre>
        <genre>Adventure</genre>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <year>2013</year>
        <trailer></trailer>
        <actor>
            <name>Keanu Reeves</name>
            <role>Kai</role>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Hiroyuki Sanada</name>
            <role>Kuranosuke Ôishi</role>
        </actor>
        <dateadded>2014-12-21 22:15:42</dateadded>
    </movie>
</videodb>
```

My asp code is as follows....

```
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")   
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("/MovieLibrary/data/videodb.xml")

Dim xmlMovies

Set xmlMovies = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("movie")
      
For Each xmlMovie In xmlMovies
    '
    Dim title:title = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("title").text
    Dim rating_value:rating_value = left(xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("ratings/rating/value").text,3)
    Dim rating_votes:rating_votes = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("ratings/rating/votes").text
    Dim plot:plot = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("plot").text
    Dim runtime:runtime = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("runtime").text
    Dim mpaa_rating:mpaa_rating = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("mpaa").text
    Dim release_year:release_year = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("year").text
    Dim id:id = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("id").text

    Dim genre:genre = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("genre").text
    
    Dim date_added:date_added = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("dateadded").text

    Dim actor:actor = xmlMovie.selectSingleNode("actor/name").text
    
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(title) & " "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(rating_value) & "/10 "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(rating_votes) & "<br>"
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(plot) & "<br>"
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(runtime) & " Minutes "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(mpaa_rating) & " "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(release_year) & " "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(id) & "<br> "
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(genre) & "<br>"
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(date_added) & "<br>"
    Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(actor) & "<br><br>"
    
Next
```

As you can see in the xml file each movie can have several "genre" entries and several "actor" entries.  I can get all the entries but I can only get the first "genre" entry and the first "actor" entry.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a sub-list of the genres listed for each movie so I can push them into my class....and I only want to grab the first 2 or three actors, not 27 as some do.

Obviously I need to create an array for the genre and actor fields but everything I try comes back with something like "this collection doesn't have this method" or nothing at all.

I know my code is messy, this is a test bed I created to make sure I can pull the new format of the file.

Any help will be appreciated. (sorry for the long post)

Comment: Never understand this, you are already iterating over the `movie` elements so what do you think you should do to iterate over the `genre` elements?

Comment: @Lankymart - XML is new to me. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around it. Sorry if my ignorance offends you.

Comment: It’s more the fact this isn’t a traditional Q&A site, the question has been handled multiple times over the years you just need to search. If you are that new to XML how did you managed to loop through the `movie` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to get the text using [selectNodes Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754523(v=vs.85))

```
Function getNodeValue(nodename)

    Dim NodeValue : NodeValue = ""
    Dim Nodes

    set Nodes = xmlMovie.selectNodes(nodename)

    For each Node in Nodes
        If NodeValue = "" Then
            NodeValue =  Node.Text
        Else
            NodeValue = NodeValue & ", " & Node.Text
        End If
    Next

    getNodeValue = NodeValue

End Function
```

This will return a comma delimited string.

Now you can get all the values like:

```
Dim title:title = getNodeValue("title")
```

and

```
Dim genre:genre = getNodeValue("genre")
```

Comment: Yeah it’s been [covered before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12075314/692942) numerous times. Not sure I'd lump them altogether in one string, the `For` loop is enough to work with them.