# getElementsByTagName returning "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error

Tags: xml, xmldom

I am working with a vendor-supplied API that returns this XML when I call it.

```
<RESPONSE>
    <VALID>true</VALID>
    <MESSAGE></MESSAGE>
    <DATA>
        <WORK>
            <ROW type="object" class="empty">
                <brief_desc>Check plate</brief_desc>
                <compid>1354</compid>
                <comp_desc>Spitfire #2</comp_desc>
                <initials></initials>
                <sch_date>2019-10-01</sch_date>
                <wo>43351</wo>
                <workstatus>O</workstatus>
                <work_desc>Check plate for flatness</work_desc>
            </ROW>
            <ROW type="object" class="empty">
                <brief_desc>Check wheel</brief_desc>
                <compid>1354</compid>
                <comp_desc>Spitfire #1</comp_desc>
                <initials></initials>
                <sch_date>2019-10-08</sch_date>
                <wo>43685</wo>
                <workstatus>O</workstatus>
                <work_desc>Check wheel for roundness</work_desc>
            </ROW>
        </WORK>
    </DATA>
</RESPONSE>
```

I call this from another vendor-supplied HMI software, that only supports VBscript.  I can  get individual values like this, using the Microsoft.XMLDOM object:

```
xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//VALID").text
```

However, when I try to get a collection of the "WORK" node, like this...

```
objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DATA")
```

...I get an error stating "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  The "DATA" element is all caps, so I think I have the name correct.  I have researched this quite a bit, but can't seem to find someone with the exact same issue.  I would appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.  Thank you!

Edit, adding full code, as requested by people replying to this post:

```
Function EmaintTest

    Dim objRequest
    Dim strUrl 
    Dim strResponse 
    Dim body 
    Dim strResponseHeaders 
    Dim allResponseHeader 
    Dim xmlDoc 
    
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://somewebsite.com/wc.dll?x3~api~&q=GetAnyData"
    
    'Set body value as required by API.
    body = "{""table"":""WORK"",""columns"":""WO,COMPID,COMP_DESC,WORKSTATUS,BRIEF_DESC,SCH_DATE,WORK_DESC,INITIALS"",""pageNumber"":1,""pageSize"":1000,""filter"":{""logic"":""and"",""filters"":[{""field"":""wo_type"",""operator"":""eq"",""value"":""PM""},{""field"":""COMPID"",""operator"":""eq"",""value"":""1354""},{""field"":""WORKSTATUS"",""operator"":""eq"",""value"":""O""}]},""sortBy"":[{""field"":""SCH_DATE"",""dir"":""asc""}]}"             
                
    With objRequest
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        .Send body
        strResponseHeaders = .StatusText
        strResponse = .ResponseText
        allResponseHeader = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
        
    'Load the XML
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = False 
    xmlDoc.loadXML(strResponse)

    'Assign variables using the values returned from the API 
    $Trace (xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//VALID").text ) 'This works, returns "True" value.

    Dim xmlNodes
    Dim xmlNode  

    Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("DATA/WORK")
    
    $Trace  ("Using selectNodes...")
    
    For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
        $Trace (xmlNode.text)
    Next
    
    $Trace  ("Using getElementsByTagName...")

    Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DATA/WORK")

    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodes
        $Trace  (xmlNode.text)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Please try the following XPath expression: `/RESPONSE/DATA`

Comment: Yitzhak - Thanks for your reply.  When I tried that, I got this error message: "Unexpected token '/'."   It might be that the version of VBScript that I'm using doesn't have this functionality (?).  Please let me know if you think of something else I could try.

Comment: The XML provided is not a **well-formed** XML. Please edit your question, and provide a real XML.

Comment: Also, please add a code to the question to make it a **minimal reproducible example.**

Comment: Yitzhak - I edited the XML example to include the final "RESPONSE" tag (for some reason, the SO editor was removing it).  My code around this is somewhat large, and not relevant to this question. I will try to remove the superfluous code and post back with a reproducible example.  Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the code that you haven't yet shared. The following code works fine with your XML file. Note that you have the option of using **selectNodes** or **getElementsByTagName**.

```
Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Load ".\Test.xml"

WScript.echo "Using selectNodes..."

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("DATA/WORK")

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  WScript.echo xmlNode.text
Next

WScript.echo "Using getElementsByTagName..."

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DATA/WORK")

For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
  WScript.echo xmlNode.text
Next
```

Here's a way to traverse all nodes:

```
Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Load ".\Test.xml"

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//*")    
For i = 0 to xmlNodes.length - 1
    WScript.Echo xmlNodes(i).nodeName & ": " & xmlNodes(i).text
Next
```

Comment: LesFerch - Thanks for your reply.  You are correct, your code works.  I have edited my original post to include the full code, including your example.  However, the For Each loop only returns a single value, which contains ALL of the data.  Ex: "Check plate 1354 Spitfire #2 2019-10-01 43351 O Check plate for flatness Check wheel 1354 Spitfire #1 2019-10-08 43685 O Check plate for roundness".  How can I get it to return individual values for each node?

Comment: I extended the answer with code to traverse all nodes. If that's what you're looking for, this would be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1908526/15764378

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12075314/15764378

Comment: LesFerch - Your method for traversing all nodes worked perfectly, so I have marked it as the answer.  Also, the other references you posted were very helpful.  Thank you very much for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a different method, i.e. `selectNodes()`.

```
objNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/RESPONSE/DATA")
```

or

```
objNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/RESPONSE/DATA/WORK/ROW")
```

Comment: Unfortunately these other methods produce the same "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" errors as the getElementsByTagName method.